# How to run stored procedure if it's in a separate schema

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, and I have created a schema `Test` and in that schema, I created a stored procedure.

I wanted to run it in the text mode by issuing this query:

```
EXEC SP_HELPTEXT SCHEMA.SPROC
```

But while running the above query I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Can someone please help me here to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this

```
EXEC SP_HELPTEXT 'SCHEMA.SPROC'
```

Answer (score 4):

`sp_helptext` to display the result when sp's or any other `tsql` binded scripts run without schema, for example:

`sp_helptext <nameof sp>`

but when you want to run it with schema name as initial then run it into single quotes

`sp_helptext 'schma.<nameofsp>`